# ngCordova contacts not available inside angular controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ngcordova

I am confused why I cannot call `$ionicPlatform` inside my controller. I can inside the angular `run()` method without a problem.

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova', 'app.controllers', 'app.services'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform, $http, $cordovaContacts, debugService) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    window.stupid = $cordovaContacts;
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
```

When I try to call it inside the controller it's empty.

```
.controller('ContactsCtrl', function($scope, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaContacts, $http, debugService) {
  window.stupid = $cordovaContacts;
  //debugService.log(ionic);
  // $cordovaContacts.find({filter: '',multiple: true,fields: ['displayName', 'name']}).then(function(allContacts){
  //     alert('cordova contacts found');
  //     debugService.log(allContacts);
  //     // This has issues
  //     $scope.contacts = contactsService.get(allContacts);
  // });

});
```

I only want to grab the contacts inside the controller and not every time the app is run. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your code in your controller `window.stupid = $cordovaContacts;` becomes initilised when `cordova` is not already ready yet.

Relating to [Common Issues with Cordova](http://ngcordova.com/docs/common-issues/) you must wrap plugin calls with the deviceready event:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
  window.stupid = $cordovaContacts;
}, false);

// OR with IONIC

$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
  window.stupid = $cordovaContacts;
});
```

So you have to wright almost the same code as you already do in your run block!

Comment: Yeah but I am saying `$ionicPlatform` is not available inside the controller

Comment: Have you injected the `ionic` dependency? You could also try global `ionic` object: `ionic.Platform.ready(function(){});`

Comment: Yeah I checked out the ionic variable earlier and it seems it was available. I didnt inspect it enough to see the Platform inside. Let me try it :)

Comment: In your controller code above i cannot see any `ionicPlatform.ready` code?! My mobile application has quite same structure and it works. Now I am confused as well ;-)

Comment: I removed it because I was playing around with other variations of code and I just happened to share my current state, sorry for the confusion. It seems `ionic.Platform.ready(function(){});` is not helping. I am very much confused as well.

Comment: I even tried turning the whole module into an es6 class and booting it up under the device ready listener.

Comment: What about using angularjs's `$window` object?